# jqGrid with multiselect: event for clicking top checkbox only?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there an event available which one can handle when clicking the checkbox in the header of a jqGrid? I tried the **onHeaderClick** but that doesn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the onSelectAll event.